# Sum of products basics (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, summation, solution-verification, expected-value

I know that for a collection of random variables $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, I have
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^nE(x_ix_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(x_i^2)+2\sum_{i<j}E(x_ix_j). \quad (a)$$
Then triangle inequality gives 
$$\Big\lvert\sum_{i,j=1}^nE(x_ix_j)\Big\rvert\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert E(x_i^2)\rvert+2\sum_{i<j}\lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert. \quad (b)$$
**My question** is: does the following hold? 
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n\Big\lvert E(x_ix_j)\Big\rvert\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert E(x_i^2)\rvert+2\sum_{i<j}\lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert. \quad (c)$$

**My attempt**

From the inequality (b), it is not  clear if the same upper bound holds for $\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert$.
But looking at the first equality (a), I see that the tuple of indices $(i,j)\in[n]^2$ can be equally partitioned as $$\{(i,j)\in[n^2]:i=j\}\cup \{(i,j)\in[n^2]:i>j\}\cup\{(i,j)\in[n^2]:i<j\}.$$
Since $\lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert=\lvert E(x_jx_i)\rvert$, I would also have 
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert E(x_i^2)\rvert +2\sum_{i<j}\lvert E(x_ix_j)\rvert,$$
which implies that (c) holds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the question? what are you trying to prove?

Comment: @Masacroso See if it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS of
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^nE(x_ix_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(x_i^2)+2\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}E(x_ix_j)\tag1
$$
is just a reordering of the LHS, therefore
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n|E(x_ix_j)|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|E(x_i^2)|+2\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}|E(x_ix_j)|\tag2
$$
There is nothing to prove here more than the use of the commutativity of the sum of real numbers, but this was already used in (1). The unique difference between (1) and (2) is that we use in (2) absolute values of it addends.

In general we have that
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{i,j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,i}+\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}a_{i,j}+\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}a_{j,i}\tag3
$$
for arbitrary complex numbers $a_{i,j}$. In your case we have that $E(x_ix_j)=E(x_jx_i)$ so
$$
\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}E(x_ix_j)+\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}E(x_j,x_i)=2\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}E(x_ix_j)\tag4
$$

Comment: Just for curiosity. Do you know what would be a generalization of (3) for $\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^n a_{i,j,k,l}$?

Comment: @CelineHarumi it depends what you mean by a "generalization" of such reordering, generalization in what sense?

Comment: A formula for $\sum_{i,j,k,l}a_{i,j,k,l}$ like in (3).